# Connect Heroku Add-on MySQL Database to DigitalOcean droplet for Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, heroku

Have anyone deployed Spring Boot app to DigitalOcean droplet?

I have previously created app on Heroku.com, where I also ordered MySQL Database and deployed my Web API. Due to performance issues, I want to transfer my Spring Boot app to DigitalOcean, but there is a problem: I still want to use DB I ordered on Heroku. I have all the required credentials, but can't find a way to connect my droplet. In Heroku, there is very simple way to do that, all I need to do is to change config variable DATABASE_URL, but here I cannot find the same. I hope you understand my problem and provide simple solution.

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called Environment Variables, here is the docs from DO.

> Specify app-level variables on the Environment screen when creating an app. For existing apps, go to the Apps section of the DigitalOcean Control Panel. Click your app, then click the Settings tab. Next to the App-Level Environment Variables heading, click the Edit link.

https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/use-environment-variables/

Comment: Deploying spring boot apps directly is currently not supported. So I created a droplet and run my project from console.

Comment: Then just create a .env file and and install dotenv package with npm i dotenv. See how to config it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv